# Trying To List All The Items From Multiple Tables In Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

Im Trying To List All The Items From Multiple Tables Into One Array using the pandas library with python  Is There A Better Way Of Doing This or a way to make it loop through till it gets each table in the array

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

weaponWikiLink = 'https://escapefromtarkov.fandom.com/wiki/Weapons'
reqWeapons = requests.get(weaponWikiLink, "lxml")
weaponsSoup = BeautifulSoup(reqWeapons.content)
weaponsTableA = weaponsSoup.find_all(name='table')

dfAR = pd.read_html(str(weaponsTableA))[0]
dfAR.head()
dfSMG = pd.read_html(str(weaponsTableA))[1]
dfSMG.head()

print (dfAR)
print (dfSMG)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://escapefromtarkov.fandom.com/wiki/Weapons"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

all_dfs = []
for t in soup.select(".wikitable"):
    for hr in t.select("hr"):
        hr.replace_with(", ")
    df = pd.read_html(StringIO(str(t)))[0]
    title = t.find_previous("h3").span.text
    df["weapon_type"] = title
    all_dfs.append(df)

df_out = pd.concat(all_dfs)
df_out.to_csv("weapons.csv", index=False)
```

This will create `weapons.csv` from all tables and in the column `weapon_type` is the title of the table.

Screenshot from LibreOffice:

[image]

Comment: If I only want to go to table 10 how would I be able to do that? Also thank you this answer helped me a lot

Comment: @LBbrowns Filter the final dataframe by desired `weapon_type`, e.g. `df_out = df_out[df_out.weapon_type == "Assault rifles"]`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering this is what I ended up doing

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from io import StringIO
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

weaponWikiLink = 'https://escapefromtarkov.fandom.com/wiki/Weapons'

weaponSoupA = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(weaponWikiLink).content, 'html.parser')

weaponDF = []

for i in weaponSoupA.select(".wikitable"):
    for hr in i.select("hr"):
        hr.replace_with(", ")
    df = pd.read_html(StringIO(str(i)))[0]
    title = i.find_previous("h3").span.text
    df["weapon_type"] = title
    weaponDF.append(df)
    

df_out = pd.concat(weaponDF)

big_df = pd.concat([df_out[df_out['weapon_type'].isin(["Shotguns", "Submachine guns", 
                                                       "Light machine guns", "Assault carbines", 
                                                       "Assault rifles", "Designated marksman rifles", 
                                                       "Sniper rifles", "Pistols"])]])
big_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

randGun = big_df.sample(n=1)

print (randGun[["Name", "Image"]])
```